# c# form, connect to database selecting random website

Tags: c#, mysql, webbrowser-control

I am trying to connect to a remote mysql database in a form based C# application. I want it so a user can click a button and it will randomly select a website url from a online database, I then want the website to be displayed within a broswer within my application. I have got it so I can hard code a website URL and it will display the website in the browser control but want to take it a step further and pull a website URL from a database.

Here is my current code

```
            webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("http://www.mintuz.co.uk");
```

And this is what I want to achieve.

Say I have 3 website URL's in a database

```
ID | Website URL

-----------------

1  | http://www.mintuz.co.uk

2  | http://www.google.com

3  | http://www.hello.com
```

I want one of those URL's to be selected randomly then shown on the browser.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could help you out

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?132,185266,194715

SELECT * FROM Table T JOIN (SELECT FLOOR(MAX(ID)*RAND()) AS ID FROM Table) AS x ON T.ID >= x.ID LIMIT 1;

Or

If you know that ID is sequential and you know the maximum ID, you can use Random class in .NET to select a random number and query the table using that ID.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx